# Using python 32 bit in 64bit platform

Tags: python, linux

In RHEL7, I have a Python 2.7.11 64bit.  I need to run 32 bit Python applications. How do I change the installed Python to run 32 bit rather than 64 bit?

Comment: I suspect that `yum install python.i686` or something like that may be a possible try, but I don't think it's a good idea - on a modern Linux system there's quite some stuff that potentially depends on Python, and replacing the system Python interpreter with a 32 bit one seems like a bad idea. You should probably perform a separate 32 bit installation of Python. OTOH, why do you care about the interpreter being 32/64 bit? "Regular" Python applications don't care about it - it's only compiled extensions that are affected (but if they are written properly, they should compile fine on 64 bit).

Answer (score 1):

Because the Python interpreter is compiled you have to download and install the 32-bit version of Python. Also I don't exactly see why you would need a 32-bit version of Python to run a script since Python is an interpreter.

[Python 2.7.12 download.](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2712/)

Comment: I actually had problems when working with some external libraries (not written only in python) when using 64 bit.

Comment: Ahh. That can happen if the libraries contain compiled code. Just download a 64-bit version of the library. If a 64-bit version is not available use 32-bit Python.

Comment: Yeah, I've had issues using pre-compiled 32 bit libraries that I don't have easy access to the source code for.